# Конкретное TextView к случайному изображению

Tags: java, android, button, textview

Приложение случайным образом меняет картинки на ImageButton. Планирую сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии на ImageButton появлялось Textview, в зависимости от того изображения, которое появилось.
Но не знаю, как это сделать

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


        final ImageButton cardbutton = findViewById(R.id.cardbutton);
        cardbutton.setTag(1);
        final TextView infotext = findViewById(R.id.infotext);


        final int[] imageIds = {
                R.drawable.n00,
                R.drawable.n01,
                R.drawable.n02,

        };

        cardbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
                if (status == 1) {

                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int randomImageId = imageIds[generator.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
                    cardbutton.setImageResource(randomImageId);
                    v.setTag(0);
                    vibrator.vibrate(50);

                } else {
                    v.setTag(1);
                }
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Сделайте нужную разметку, и работайте с Visible TextView.

Comment: Добрый лень! Спасибо за ответ)Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как связать нужное мне TextView с изображением, которое появляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте два массива с соответствиями id картинок и текста для них. По индексу массива получаете нужную картинку в первом массиве и соответствующий ей текст во втором или pojo-объекты с двумя полями: id картинки и текст для нее, которые складывайте в массив или коллекцию

например:

```
 final int[] imageIds = {
            R.drawable.n00,
            R.drawable.n01,
            R.drawable.n02,

    };


final String[] texts= {
            "текст1",
           "текст2",
            "текст3"
    };

    cardbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (status == 1) {

                Random generator = new Random();
                int index = generator.nextInt(imageIds.length);
                int randomImageId = imageIds[index];
                String text = texts[index];
                cardbutton.setImageResource(randomImageId);
                infotext.setText(text);
                v.setTag(0);
                vibrator.vibrate(50);

            } else {
                v.setTag(1);
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: Спасибо) Код сначала не загрузился. Однако здесь TextView будет загружаться сразу. Я планирую, что бы он загружался уже по повторному клику на кноку. Это можно решить добавлением Text.visible в else?

Comment: вы программист, вы можете решить задачу любым доступным вам способом. Я лишь привел пример, как связать два типа данных, о чем вы и спрашивали в вопросе. Писать полную реализацию вашей идеи у меня нет ни времени, ни желания, прошу понять и простить

Comment: Куда уж мне до программиста) Большое спасибо за помощь